# How to prevent "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header contain multiple value

Tags: node.js, nginx

This is my Nginx CORS config:

```
set $cors '';

if ($http_origin ~ '^https?://(localhost|www\.beloveddais\.com|www\.beloveddais\.com)') {
    set $cors 'true';
}


if ($cors = 'true') {
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' "$http_origin" always;
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true' always;
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS' always;
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Accept,Authorization,Cache-Control,Content-Type,DNT,If-Modified-Since,Keep-Alive,Origin,User-Agent,X-Requested-With' always;
    # required to be able to read Authorization header in frontend
    add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Authorization' always;
}

if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
    # Tell client that this pre-flight info is valid for 20 days
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' "$http_origin" always;
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true' always;
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Accept,Authorization,Cache-Control,Content-Type,DNT,If-Modified-Since,Keep-Alive,Origin,User-Agent,X-Requested-With' always;
    add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
    add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain charset=UTF-8';
    add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
    return 204;
}

if ($request_method = 'GET') {
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' "$http_origin" always;
}

if ($request_method = 'POST') {
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' "$http_origin" always;
}
```

On my browser console I keep getting:

> Failed to load
>   http://beloveddais.win/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=M6yTqBe:
>   The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values
>   'http://beloveddais.com, http://beloveddais.com', but only one is
>   allowed. Origin 'http://beloveddais.com' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

Please I need help to prevent this multiple header stuff. This has really wasted my time.

Comment: @Iloiacono: you still have not answered the question, that is more important.

Comment: Did you finally find out a solution for this ? I'm in the same situation, and totally stuck.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your config is adding `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` twice.
This is because of construction of your config file.
1st time it is added because of `($cors = 'true')` condition, and 2nd time because of `($request_method = 'OPTIONS')` condition.

You should make clear policy of sending headers and prepare conditions so they are mutual exclusive, so no header will be sent multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same error in following scenario.

I have Springboot RESTAPI and Angular client.

Angular Client calls the API and all end points are behaving as expected.

**CAUSE (IN MY SCENARIO)**

However, one endpoint in my API calls another API.

That other API returns response including the headers containing its own `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`.  Then my API adds its own `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` resulting in two `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` headers which is not allowed by browsers.

My CORS settings are right because I know all other endpoints are working fine and are returning only one `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`.

**SOLUTION**

So, the solution I did is that in the Controller calling other API, and once other API returns response, I would get the body out of that response and create a new `ResponseEntity` from it.

This results in only my API returning its own `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` and all is working fine.

I hope this explanation of the cause and solution will help others since I see lots of people are asking the same question.